# Max Output Cache Size ASP.NET IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

What is the maximum output cache size for ASP.NET in IIS 6? Is it configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some details that the Cache element in the web.config will set this value, but the real answer is pretty complicated. The default is something like 60% of available RAM; however what you have to take into account is that W3WP is only capable of addressing roughly 2 GB of RAM in a 32 bit OS (such as Server 2003). This means that across all application pools (read as all processes) the total RAM usage of W3WP cannot exceed that threshold, regardless of whether you're running Server 2003 Enterprise with over 4 GB of RAM.

Short story is that unless you're running a 64 bit OS, you'll run into memory pressure related issues around 800-1200 MB of RAM usage by W3WP